# Apple Watch : will the App on iPhone run in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch

Am trying a simple Apple Watch App. the question I have is : will the iPhone App be able to run always in the background? In the App, I want to fetch some files from a server & store them in the iPhone (I want to do this everyday at a  specific time), so that when the user opens the Apple Watch App, the file can be showed immediately (and no need to wait for it be downloaded then).

Comment: Yes, it runs in the background, you can call the iPhone from the Watch using https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:

Answer (score -1):

You can run tasks in the background of an iPhone application yes. I have no idea about how this interacts with the Apple Watch (your post suggests this will just sync automatically perhaps). Good point of reading:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Hi @The Senator, thanks for your response. Will look into this & get back!

Comment: Something I said down-voter? Would you care to illuminate us all with what you've learned? I'd like to know what I've said is wrong so I can further my own nefarious gains also. Thanks.